# LyX: Display exercise number correctly when using Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type within Chapters)

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX with the "Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type within Chapters)" module. Using the exercise layout (which corresponds to `xcc` LaTeX environment), I am able to generate a PDF with correct numbers by chapter. However, inside LyX, the minor number doesn't restart each chapter. Is there a setting somewhere for LyX to display numbers correctly, or is it a bug?

E.g. -- in LyX:

[image]

In PDF:

[image]

Comment: Does LyX ship with that layout or did you download it from somewhere else? Could you give the exact title that LyX shows that layout as?

Comment: @scottkosty -- missed plural "theorem" and "chapter" -- corrected in question now. Believe that they are shipped by default.

Comment: Ah I had misread something actually. My fault. Thanks for the corrections in any case. I suggest you post a minimal example .lyx file on https://www.lyx.org/trac. Choose the component "layout".